# How do i convert number from one language to another using flutter_localizations

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization

```
"digits": "{number}",
  "@digits": {
    "description": "Can be any number",
    "placeholders": {
      "number": {
        "type": "num"
      }
    }
  }
```

Currently i am using this code in the `app_en.arb` file. I want the user to enter any number and that number should be translated to particular locale.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, could you provide an exemple of the result you are expecting ? If you want to translate "one" and "two" you need to explicitly provide the translation for both of them with this method. The parameters are here to integrate easily with your code and use it for plural for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom number format, use the international way in the json object and then transform it with the format you want, do a switch case or Map to select the format depending on the localization.

```
String stringValue = '123.45'; // Replace with your string value
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.decimalPattern(); // You can choose a format based on your localization
Number? parsedNumber = numberFormat.parse(stringValue);
if (parsedNumber != null) {
  double result = parsedNumber.toDouble();
  print(result); // This is the parsed number as a double
} else {
  print('Invalid number format');
}
```